# 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Unable to find git in your PATH

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I could not run "flutter create projectName" in my terminal. It only shows this error. I need help. I'm stuck and don't know what to do to run.

Comment: do you have git installed?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also pasted it in my path variables but still, it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing git on your computer

Comment: Yes, and I added it to my path. Still, it gives the same response.

Comment: try execute git --version command on console, if everything is right it will return the version of your installed git

Comment: It did, now my problem's on android studio. It shows that Applications 1, 2, 3, and 4 does not exist.